# Заливка большого файла на WEB сервер методом POST python

Tags: python, сервер, http, post, requests

Помогите разобраться в чем проблема.
Хочу залить файл на сервер, использую библиотеку requests.
Маленький файл льется отлично, с большим файлом беда - не уходит.
Код:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('запорос на урл')
upload_url = r['урл сервера']
file = {'video_file': ('1.mp4', open('S:/1.mp4', 'rb'))}
r2 = requests.post(upload_url, files=file)
```

ответ питона

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "S:/charm/projects/2.py", line 13, in <module>
    r2 = requests.post(upload_url, files=file)
  File "S:\charm\projects\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 112, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "S:\charm\projects\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "S:\charm\projects\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 494, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "S:\charm\projects\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 437, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "S:\charm\projects\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 308, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
  File "S:\charm\projects\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 496, in prepare_body
    (body, content_type) = self._encode_files(files, data)
  File "S:\charm\projects\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 159, in _encode_files
    fdata = fp.read()
MemoryError
```

Повторю, маленькие файлы грузит отлично.
Что не так?

Comment: Памяти не хватает. *read()* без параметра и проверок возврата — зло. Ну и вообще, научитесь читать tracebacks от питона. Будет гораздо легче.

Comment: А какой размер 1.mp4 и сколько у вас оперативы? Питон 32-битный?

Comment: Питон и 32 и 64 пробовал, размер файла более 200мб уже точно не льет.

Comment: related: [python requests upload large file with additional data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35779879/4279)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать [requests-toolbelt](https://github.com/requests/toolbelt):

```
# pip install requests-toolbelt
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder

# pip install requests
import requests


upload_file = open('S:/1.mp4', 'rb')
payload = MultipartEncoder({'1.mp4': upload_file})

rs = requests.post('<url>', data=payload , headers={'Content-Type': payload.content_type})
print(rs)
```

Comment: Бро, спасибо за наводку, MultipartEncoder решил проблему.

Comment: Про сам модуль не читал, но этот способ не грузит память. В свой код я добавил только import MultipartEncoder и payload = MultipartEncoder(file_)

Comment: @Zen, код в ответе у вас не работает?

Comment: Не смог в свой код воткнуть Ваш полностью. Просто весь мой  код немного больше с использованием цикла и переменных вместо прямого пути, а знаний питона у меня мало, эт первая программа. Модуль мультипарт добавил «методом тыка» и к счастью он сработал идеально. Но скорость загрузки медленная(

Comment: @Zen, честно, не знаю почему оно медленно работает. Предлагаю вам создать новый вопрос с этой проблемой

Comment: @Zen медленная по сравнению с чем? С локальным сервером тестировали? (`nc -l 1111 | pv>/dev/null` подойдёт). Создайте минимальный пример и как отдельный вопрос задайте.

Comment: Медленная по сравнению с закачкой через браузер. Моя програмка грузит на сервер через апи видео.

Answer (score 4):

Если сервер может напрямую файл принимать (в http message-body), то [достаточно файл как data передать](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads):

```
import requests

with open('1.mp4', 'rb') as file:
    requests.post(url, data=file)
```

Comment: Так пробовал, с большими файлами не проходит

Comment: @Zen что значит с "большими файлами не проходит"? Код в ответе как с маленькими так и большими файлами одинаково работает. Если сервер принимает маленький файл, но большой не принимает—это ошибка на стороне сервера. Код в ответе (на клиенте) реализует streaming upload.

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы послать файл на сервер, используя `multipart/form-data` Сontent-Type как `<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data>` c `<input name="file" type="file">` html-элементом в браузере делают, [можно `pycurl` использовать](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/quickstart.html#file-upload):

```
import pycurl

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, url)
c.setopt(c.HTTPPOST, [('file', (c.FORM_FILE, filename))])
c.perform()
c.close()
```