# Медленная загрузка файла на сервер, используя requests_toolbelt.MultipartEncoder

Tags: python, post, api, request, fileupload

Работаю с pycharm. Пишу загрузчик видео через апи на сервер вк. В целом все просто - получил ссылку и залил видео методом POST на сервер. Но проблема в том что загрузка видео через питон идет ооочень долго, раз в 10 медленнее точно.
Вот так загружаю файл

```
import requests
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder

file_ = {'video_file': (mp4, open(full_dir, 'rb'))}
upload_url = '<url>'
payload = MultipartEncoder(file_)
r = requests.post(upload_url, data=payload, headers={'Content-Type': payload.content_type})
```

Собственно вопрос - от чего такая медленная скорость загрузки и можно ли ее как-то увеличить. Сервера контакта и мой канал точно не при чем.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Результаты измерений с локальным сервером `nc -l 1111 | pv >/dev/null` на моей машине:

```
| method                          | 100 MiB/s |
|---------------------------------+-----------|
| ordinary post                   |         5 |
| MultipartEncoder                |       0.5 |
| MultipartEncoder patched read() |         5 |
| curl                            |         5 |
| pycurl                          |         5 |
```

где

- [ordinary post](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/831654/23044)
- "MultipartEncoder" метод аналогичен коду в вопросе
- сurl

  ```
  $ curl -v -H "filename: $filename" \
          -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
          -F "filename=$filename" \
          -F "file=@$filename;type=application/octet-stream" \
          -X POST $url
  ```
- [pycurl](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/832055/23044)

а "MultipartEncoder patched read()":

```
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder import MultipartEncoder

files = {filename: open(filename, 'rb')}
m = MultipartEncoder(files)  # streaming
# improve performance
# https://github.com/requests/toolbelt/issues/75#issuecomment-237189952
m._read = m.read
m.read = lambda size: m._read(1024*1024)
r = requests.post(url, data=m, headers={'Content-Type': m.content_type})
```

[Документация MultipartEncoder](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uploading-data.html#requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder.MultipartEncoder) содержит предупреждение:

> This object [encoder] will end up directly in `httplib`. Currently,
>   httplib has a hard-coded read size of **8192** bytes.

Из-за относительно маленького размера буфера может ухудшаться скорость. Результаты измерений показывают, что увеличивая размер буфера, [заменяя `m.read()`](https://github.com/requests/toolbelt/issues/75#issuecomment-237189952), можно заметно улучшить производительность.

Стоит упомянуть, что во многих ситуациях узким местом может быть не код, а скорость чтения с диска, пропускная способность сети, производительность удалённого сервера. Всегда измеряйте, прежде чем изменять код.

Comment: В плане производительности железа все ок. Возможно через апи контакта режется скорость, я еще задам этот вопрос их тп. В любом случае Вам спасибо за ответ, возможно дело в буфере, буду пробовать :)

Comment: Использовал метод m.read - работает как-то странно, сам выбирает с какой скоростью грузить - либо 15% либо 90-65% (замеры загрузки сетевой карты из диспетчера задач)  Замер после скачка в 50%, грузил циклом 3 видео  [https://ibb.co/in5swT ]

Comment: @Zen: у вас сеть 100Мбит/с, то есть даже относительно медленный вариант с MultipartEncoder (без модификаций read()) в несколько раз быстрее  чем сеть позволяет работает. То есть код в вопросе уже и так достаточно быстрый должен быть. Сравните с pycurl вариантом (несколько раз попробуйте разные варианты с похожим кодом). Я ожидаю, что скорость ограничивается внешними факторами поэтому, если ошибки в сравнении нет, то похожие результаты по производительности получите.

Comment: Спасибо за советы, буду тестить, по результатам опишу)

Comment: В общем код и правда не при чем, отрабатывает отлично. Пробовал с m.read и без, замеры показали что первый вариант значительно быстрее работает. Заработало после перезагрузки pycharm. Возможно на стороне вк были проблемы @jfs Вам огромное спасибо, сам бы мучался еще неделю точно!!!